# Returning Support Vector Machine Feature Coefficients

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to return the feature names and the coefficients from the Support Vector Machine. Below is the code have.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='rbf').fit(X_train, y_train)

svm_coeff_list = np.array(svclassifier.coef_).tolist()
```

It keeps giving me

```
AttributeError: coef_ is only available when using a linear kernel
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is no coef_ in case of radial-basis kernel.

SVM works on the basis of support vectors (the most important pertaining to a particular class).

In case of rbf kernel, you can use `dual_coef_` and `support_vectors_`.

For multiclass, coefficient for all 1-vs-1 classifiers will be held by `dual_coef_`.

The order of coefficients wille (1st class, 2nd class), (1st class, 3rd class), ... (1st class, nth class), (2nd class, 3rd class), and so on.

And if you want `coef_`, then change your kernel to linear but it is less powerful in case of predictive power.